# Python generics: user defined generic in a callable

Tags: python, generics, python-typing

I have the following setup:

```
T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclass
class Type(Generic[T]):
    name: str
    data: T


@dataclass
class Aspect:
    name: str
    from: Type[str]
    to: Type[int]
    func: Callable[[Type[str]], Type[int]]
```

This works great, but I've tied my Callable to str and int, and I would want something even more generic like being able to define func as something like:

```
func: Callable[[Type[A]], Type[B]]
```

where A and B can be whatever, so I can define and send a func like `(a: Type[str]) -> Type[int]:...`
or `(a: Type[float]) -> Type[str]:...` or whatever

Right now I can have a function:

```
def func1(a: Type[str]) -> Type[int]:
    return Type("func1", 1)
```

which I can use to create an Aspect `Aspect("asp1", type1, type2, func1)`

But I can't create an Aspect in the same way with a function like:

```
def func2(a: Type[int]) -> Type[str]:
    return Type("func2", "2")
```

and then call `Aspect("asp1", type1, type2, func2)`

I've tried creating different TypeVars to use in the callable, but it doesn't work, mypy says they are unbound, I've also tried to work around this with ABC but to no success, is there any way to express this?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you mean, but if you want to genericize those parameters as well you need to make those generic parameters of Aspect. Alternatively, if you don't care about type safety then make it `Type[Any]`.

Comment: I mean right now the only functions I can use for Aspect must have the Type[str] -> Type[int].
```
def func1(a: Type[str]) -> Type[int]:
   return Type("func1", 1)
```

but I might want an Aspect with a different function like:
```
def func2(a: Type[float]) -> Type[str]:
    return Type("func2", "2")
```
and right now with the Callable definition I can't do that.

Comment: If you are completely new to the concept of generics I'd recommend not doing them in Python first. They are quite obscure and imo ill done in Python. Read about them in a Java or C# tutorial. They are easier to grasp in statically typed languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics allow you to bind a generic type `T`, `A`, or `B` to a concrete type within a class or function. In your case you want every instance of `A` and `B` represent the same type across the entire class, therefore you must bind
`A` and `B` inside a class by extending `Generic[A, B]`.

```
T = TypeVar('T')
A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')


@dataclass
class MyType(Generic[T]):
  name: str
  data: T


@dataclass
class Aspect(Generic[A, B]):
  name: str
  from_: MyType[A]
  to: MyType[B]
  func: Callable[[MyType[A]], MyType[B]]
```

(changed `Type` to `MyType` to avoid confusion with `typing.Type`)
It essentially tells python: "Let's define `A` and `B` to mean the same thing across the class"

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of extending from Generic(A, B), though I did use the type vars A and B.